# How to import external javascript in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux

I have a form where i need to ask the user to enter the location.
So I am using npm package **react-geosuggest-plus**, But i dont want to put `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAjmry-FVO4U1mTEtvYnYHsBPfVmNicsZsw&libraries=places"></script>`

this in the header section of html page, since i am using this library only in one file. 
I am using react-redux with webpack as codebase. 
Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Webpack, you should add Babel. Then you can use ES6 importing:

```
import 'react-geosuggest-plus'
```

Comment: Yes after importing the npm package need to add below url in the header section, so i am trying to find out how can i avoid it, since i am using this extra call for only one form. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAjmry-FVO4U1mTEtvYnYHsBPfVmNicsZsw&libraries=places

Comment: The link you have is an API, not just a script. Once you import it, you need to make an AJAX call to get the specific data you want.

Comment: Yes i am doing it and its working, but specifically i am looking for some way to use that api like  "import <url>" instead of adding in header, since same header i am using in every page so i can avoid an extra api call for other pages.

Comment: When you do the API call, save the data in a variable that you can then access anywhere.

Comment: Are you saying copy the data from the api call and then import and use it?

Comment: Yeah, so in the successful API call, just save the entire JSON object it returns as a variable.